# How to validate presence of an array using Enumerize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerize

I'm trying to implement to validations on a given model array-like field, using the Enumerize Gem. I want to:

- validate that all the elements of a list belong to a given subset, using Enumerize
- validate that the list is not empty (using `validates :field, presence: true`)

It seems that when I provide a list containing an empty string, the presence validator fails. See this example.

```
class MyModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend Enumerize

  enumerize :cities, in: %w(Boston London Berlin Paris), multiple: true
  validates :cities, presence: true
end


# Does not behave as expected
a = MyModel.new(cities: [""])
a.cities.present?  # => false
a.valid?  # => true, while it should be false.
```

It seems to work in some other cases (for instance when you provide a non empty string that is not in the Enum). For instance

```
# Behaves as expected
a = MyModel.new(cities: ["Dublin"])
a.cities.present?  # => false
a.valid?  # => false
```

Is there a workaround available to be able to use both Enumerize validation and ActiveModel presence validation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enumerize` gem is saving your multiple values as an string array. Something like this: `"[\"Boston\"]"`. So, with an empty array you have: `"[]"`. The `presence`validator uses [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) method to check if the value is present or not. `"[]".blank?` returns `false` obviously.

So, you can try some alternatives:

#### Option 1:

```
validates :cities, inclusion: { in: %w(Boston London Berlin Paris) }
```

#### Option 2:

Add a custom validator

```
validate :ensure_valid_cities

def ensure_valid_cities
  errors.add(:cities, "invalid") unless cities.values.empty?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went for the custom validator option in the end. Enumerize actually stores the value as a list with an empty string `[""]`, and this is not handled properly by the gem for now. There is a PR open about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug that should be fixed in a later version of Enumerize (See https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize/pull/226).

In the meantime, you can use a **custom validator** as a workaround (See Leantraxx's answer).